# page loads with no css styling

Tags: codeigniter

I created a blog using codeigniter with two posts, each post has a "*read more*" link, that takes you to another page.

To style the page, I used bootstrap.min.css, which I downloaded from bootswatch. It is embedded in a header template I created.

I don't understand why the "*read more*" page loads with no css styling?

Comment: Have you tried looking in browser's developer tools to see if css file has loaded?

Comment: Yes but it shows no rules

Comment: I don't know if that may help you understand the problem I am really new to this

Comment: The bootstrap. min.css  shows no rules

Comment: what is the url of the bootstrap.min.css file?

Comment: http://local host/ciblog/post/assets/css./bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I saved it in the assets folder

Comment: If the .css file is empty download it again from a reliable source. Or even easier just access it from a server directly using http or https.